# Dokku release fails with failure injecting docker labels on image

Tags: dokku

I am trying to deploy an app to dokku from a docker container.
I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: dokku/myapp-server:latest: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
 !     Failure injecting docker labels on image
fatal: master^: not a valid SHA1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this particular case is that the user built the image on an ARM Mac as a linux/arm64 image, but their server is linux/amd64. When Dokku stamps an image for release, it will use a Dockerfile to build a new image with the correct tags/labels. Dokku will pull the image - as normal - and then Docker won't be able to "see" the image since the platform it is running as is amd64.

The workarounds is to use [buildx](https://docs.docker.com/build/install-buildx/) to build the image being deployed:

```bash
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 -t <image-name> .
```

Note: I was helping @michal-bachratý on the Dokku discord [here](https://discord.com/channels/952684157123837952/1089394081559478284).